# why a null node putted in stack

Tags: c, debugging

i have my bitree preorder traversal algorithm like this

```or-tag-here
  void Postorder_stack(BiTree T)
{
  sqstack s,k;
  InitStack(&s);
  InitStack(&k);
  BiTree p=T;
  push(&s,p);
  while(!StackEmpty(s))
    {
      pop(&s,&p);
      push(&k,p);    
      if(p->lch!=NULL);
      push(&s,p->lch);
      if(p->rch!=NULL)
    push(&s,p->rch);
    }
  while(!StackEmpty(k))
    {
      pop(&k,&p);
    printf("%c",p->data);
    }

}
```

when i use gdb to debug step by step i found that the NULL T push into stack,for example:

```or-tag-here
  (gdb) p s
$6 = {top = 0x603178, base = 0x603170, stacksize = 10}
(gdb) p p.lch
$7 = (BiNode *) 0x0
(gdb) step
push (s=0x7fffffffddc0, e=0x0) at test_bitree.cpp:55 //p.lch is NULL but it push into stack
55  *((*s).top)++=e;
(gdb) p e
$8 = (BiTree) 0x0
(gdb) step
58  }
(gdb) 

Breakpoint 3, Postorder_stack (T=0x603010) at test_bitree.cpp:136
136       if(p->rch!=NULL)
(gdb) p p->rch
$9 = (BiNode *) 0x0
(gdb) p s
$10 = {top = 0x603180, base = 0x603170, stacksize = 10}
(gdb) step
```

i use 'abd##e##c##' for the test, the whole program i put here 
thank you!

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct BiNode {
    char data;
    struct BiNode *lch;
    struct BiNode *rch;
}BiNode;
typedef struct BiNode *BiTree;
struct sqstack{
    BiTree *top,*base;
    int stacksize;
};

void InitStack(sqstack *s)
{
  (*s).base=(BiTree*)malloc(10*sizeof(BiTree));
  (*s).top=(*s).base;
  (*s).stacksize=10;
}
int StackEmpty(sqstack s)
{
  if(s.top==s.base)
    return 1;
  else return 0;
}

int Gettop(sqstack s,BiTree *e)
{
  if(s.top>s.base)
    {
      *e=*(s.top-1);
      return 1;
    }
  else return 0;
}
void push(sqstack *s,BiTree e)
{
*((*s).top)++=e;
// *(*s).top=e;
// *((*s).top)++;
}
int pop(sqstack *s,BiTree *e)
{
  if((*s).top==(*s).base)
    return 0;
  else{
      *e=*--(*s).top;
      return 1;
  }
}

void CreatBitree(BiTree *T)
{
  char ch;
  scanf("%c",&ch);
  if(ch=='#')
    *T=NULL;
  else
   {
      *T=(BiTree)malloc(sizeof(BiNode));
      (*T)->data=ch;
       CreatBitree(&(*T)->lch);
       CreatBitree(&(*T)->rch);
    }
}
void Preorder_stack(BiTree T)
{
  BiTree p=T;
  sqstack s;
  InitStack(&s);
  push(&s,T);
  while(!StackEmpty(s))
    {
      while(Gettop(s,&p)&&p)
    {
      printf("%c",p->data);
      push(&s,p->lch);
    }
      pop(&s,&p);
      if(!StackEmpty(s))
    {
      pop(&s,&p);
      push(&s,p->rch);
    }
    }
}
void Inorder_stack(BiTree T)
{
  sqstack s;
  BiTree p;
  InitStack(&s);
  push(&s,T);
  while(!StackEmpty(s))
    {
      while(Gettop(s,&p)&&p)
    push(&s,p->lch);
      pop(&s,&p);
      if(!StackEmpty(s))
    {
      pop(&s,&p);
      printf("%c",p->data);
      push(&s,p->rch);
    }
    }
}
void Postorder_stack(BiTree T)
{
  sqstack s,k;
  InitStack(&s);
  InitStack(&k);
  BiTree p=T;
  push(&s,p);
  while(!StackEmpty(s))
    {
      pop(&s,&p);
      push(&k,p);
      if(p->lch!=NULL);
      push(&s,p->lch);
      if(p->rch!=NULL)
    push(&s,p->rch);
    }
  while(!StackEmpty(k))
    {
      pop(&k,&p);
    printf("%c",p->data);
    }

}
void InitBitree (BiTree *T)
{
  *T=NULL;
}
int  main()
{
  BiTree T;
  InitBitree(&T);
  CreatBitree(&T);
Preorder_stack(T);
Inorder_stack(T);
Postorder_stack(T);
}
```

Comment: Hello! You might want to look into making this code into more of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
if(p->lch!=NULL);
      // right  ^ here
      push(&s,p->lch);
```

You have an undesired semicolon that causes a push without any protection. You need to have:

```
if(p->lch!=NULL)
      push(&s,p->lch);
```

Comment: thank you very much !you know i have been confused by three weeks.i thought it was something wrong with push()function